# access issue in uploading SSL file in amazon EC2 server

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2

i am using this command to upload ssl file.

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name CertificateName --certificate-body file://public_key_certificate_file --private-key  file://privatekey.pem
```

i also placed a config file at  `~/.aws/config`
and values are

```
[default]

aws_access_key_id = with my own key 

aws_secret_access_key = with my own key

region = ********
```

but it is giving me this error:

A client error (AccessDenied) occurred: User: arn:aws:iam::419351825566:user/**** is not authorized to perform: iam:UploadServerCertificate on resource: arn:a
ws:iam::419351825566:server-certificate/****.crt

Am I not writing AWS Credentials properly? Or I have no access?  I am also not sure if I am writing region right..

Comment: Does your IAM user actually have permission to access the iam:UploadServerCertificate action?

Comment: does not know. root user saying i have all rights

Comment: Region should be something like "us-west-2". I had this problem too, make sure you've set a policy for your user that allows iam:UploadServerCertificate, and also ensure that user's security group is assigned to your EC2 instance

Comment: @anthonygore can you say a little more about 1) setting a specific policy to allow iam:UploadServerCertificate? Also, do you have to launch the instance with this security group instead of adding it later? I am launching a node server from AWS CLI but do not see how to include a command line argument to include a specific user group

Answer (score 23):

**As of Nov 2015, having an IAM user with a policy of 'IAMFullAccess' will make this work.** You can create a new user to have that sole policy, or you can use an existing user and just add the policy.

**Note: After uploading the SSL file, you can remove the IAMFullAccess policy if you'd like to tighten down permissions/security again.**

New user workflow:

1. In the jumbo Services menu in AWS, go to IAM
2. In left sidebar, click on Users
3. Click blue "Create New Users" button
4. Type in a name for the user, e.g. "ssl-uploader", and create user
5. Make note of the keys that AWS gives you. You can't retrieve these later (you'd have to go back to step 1 and create a different user).
6. Assign the `IAMFullAccess` policy to the new user
7. In command line, do `aws configure` and answer the questions:

   - `AWS Access Key ID:` - access key from step 5
   - `AWS Secret Access Key:` - secret key from step 5
   - `Default region name:` - didn't matter in my case, accepted default `None`
   - `Default output format:` - didn't matter in my case, accepted default `None`
8. Run command as mentioned in the question, and it should work. You may want to take note of the JSON it returns in case you need it later.

Comment: Same for me. It's totally sufficient to add the policy. No need to create a new user.

Comment: @Steven agreed - updated my answer to clarify. Thanks